# GUI Shop with multiple buttons, equip item, buy item, and check if already has item

Tags: button, scripting, lua, roblox

The code I posted is meant to do three things:

1. Set `item.DoesOwn.Value` to true when buyButton is pressed
2. Make equipButton visible when `item.DoesOwn.Value` is true
3. Unequip all items, then equip the selected item when equip is pressed.

**THE Problem:** When I click multiple item buttons, then click buyButton, it sets all the buttons' `DoesOwn.Value` properties to true. I only want to buy 1 item at a time, and only if it's not already owned. The same goes with equipping 1 item at a time when they already own the item.

```
previewBox=script.Parent.PreviewImage
itemLabel=script.Parent.ItemName
priceLabel=script.Parent.PriceLabel

equipButton=script.Parent.Equip
buyButton=script.Parent.Buy

knifeItems=script.Parent.KnifeFrame:GetChildren()

function checkKnifeItems(button,buttons)
    previewBox.Image=button.Image
    itemLabel.Text=button.Name

    if button.DoesOwn.Value == true and button.Equipped.Value == false then 

        priceLabel.Visible=false
        equipButton.Visible=true
        equipButton.MouseButton1Down:connect(function()
            for i, v in pairs(buttons) do
                buttons[i].Equipped.Value=false
            end

            button.Equipped.Value=true
            equipButton.Visible=false
            button.BackgroundColor3=Color3.new(0/277, 255/277, 127/277)
        end)
    elseif button.DoesOwn.Value == false then
        equipButton.Visible=false
        buyButton.Visible=true
        buyButton.MouseButton1Down:connect(function()
            button.DoesOwn.Value=true
            button.BackgroundColor3=Color3.new(255/277, 255/277, 255/277)
            buyButton.Visible=false
        end)
    end
end

for i,v in pairs (knifeItems) do
    v.MouseButton1Down:connect(function()checkKnifeItems(v,knifeItems) end)
end
```

Comment: The lack of indentation makes that code *very* hard to read. How about indenting the contents of `if` ... `end` blocks? (Plus `for` ... `do` ... `end` and so on).

Comment: Thanks for fixing indenting, im new to this website, but do you know what's wrong with this code?

Answer (score 0):

Never mind i fixed it my self, it was simple debounce issue.

Answer (score 0):

Yes i agree that it is a simple issue. you could easily fix it if you invested a few minutes of your time. i know a good coder guy on roblox if you want his user name:person299